# Android default menu button is not visible

Tags: android

in my app the android default menu button is not visible? why? Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer this:
[On Android Honeycomb how do I add option menu to the home bar at the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401841/on-android-honeycomb-how-do-i-add-option-menu-to-the-home-bar-at-the-bottom-of-t)

And this:
[onCreate Options menu is not showing in android 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061409/oncreate-options-menu-is-not-showing-in-android-3-1)

You can simple edit target SDK in manifest file to force use SDK of mobile rather than tablet like this:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="10"
```

Comment: Simple but the best solution for old style Option Menu :D. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not only should your apps stop relying on the hardware Menu button, but you should stop thinking about your activities using a “menu button” at all.**Your activities should provide buttons for important user actions directly in the action bar (or elsewhere on screen).** Those that can’t fit in the action bar end up in the **action overflow.**
In order to provide the most intuitive and consistent user experience in your apps, you should migrate your designs away from using the Menu button and toward using the action bar.
Ice Cream Sandwich rolls out to more devices, it’s important that you begin to migrate your designs to the action bar in order to promote a consistent Android user experience.[See this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you hook up a xml menu file to your activity ?

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xmlfilename, (android.view.Menu) menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: im not using that function because i dont handle menu button! i just want to know why it is not visible.. for all othr apps its working..